# Close Jquery dialog based on resulted validation

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, form-submit

I am loading a `PartialView` into a `Jquery UI dialog` and if something went wrong during the `post method` I reload the `PartialView` into the dialog again ( `ModelState` errors for example ) . At this point my ajax sumbit doesn't work anymore. It justs redirect me and it should not.

What is wrong in my code ?  Here is what I have tried :

```
$('#editdialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: '900px',
        modal: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).load('Controller action', function (html) {
                $('#incarcerationForm').submit(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'Controller action',
                        data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#editdialog').html(data);

                            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("#myForm"));

                            if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
                                GetDetails(@Model.FormModel.ID);
                                $('#editdialog').dialog('close');
                                console.log("myForm was edited successfully");
                                return false;
                            }

                            return false;

                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            $('#editdialog').html(data);
                            console.log("error at edit myForm");
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
                return false;
            });
        }

    });
```

And my `[HttpPost]` `Controller` action :

```cs
  public ActionResult Create(Mymodel viewModel)
    {   
         return CheckValidBusiness(() => 
           { 
             viewModel.Save(viewModel.FormModel); return true; 
           })
        .Valid(() => PartialView(viewModel))
        .Invalid(() => PartialView(viewModel));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
$('#incarcerationForm').submit(function () {
```

with:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#incarcerationForm', function () {
```

so that you subscribe to the submit event of the form in a *lively manner* which will be resilient to DOM changes. Take a look at the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method for more information.

Comment: Good one. Thank you very much !!  That solves my submit problem, but how can I verify if there exists validation errors ? I mean, If submit was completed to close the dialog box.  if ($("#myForm").valid()) { doesn't work

Comment: You could have your controller action return a PartialViewResult containing the form with the validation errors in case of an error and a JsonResult in case of success. Then inside the success callback of your AJAX request you could test in which case you are and act accordingly.

Comment: I love you !!! :)) . I thought at that but I didn't know it will work if my return type is ActionResult and I've never tried .